# How to remove default mouse-over effect on WPF buttons?

Tags: wpf, button, mouseover

My problem is that in WPF, whenever I try and change the colour of a button's background using triggers or animations, the default mouseover effect (of being grey with that orange glow) seems to take priority.

After extensive searches I'm clueless as to how to remove this effect.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to create your own custom button template to have full control over the appearance in all states. Here's a [tutorial](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2007/07/creating-custom-wpf-button-template-in.html).

Comment: Thanks, that was perfect. It was more complicated to do than I thought it would be, but it all works well now.

Comment: For some reason there's 100 answers about creating custom templates for WPF controls, and they are all unnecessarily wrong. There's no reason to struggle to write 50 lines of template code for a button in order to change 1 thing. All you have to do is in the xaml designer right click the control and create a copy of the template code. VS will create a style from that exact button and you can tweak it from there. Takes literally 2 seconds.

Comment: @TheMuffinMan Fantastic, but do you find it even slightly strange that it takes 50 lines of template code to stop a button from changing the background color on mouse hover? What a stupidly over complicated framework WPF is.

Comment: @Ash Or one could argue it's guiding the user in the direction they *should* be going. If you have a button that requires a new hover state, that's likely a new TYPE of button; perhaps a navigation button, a tray button, etc. If so, you shouldn't be modifying one-off properties for it, it should have its own control or style group. And that's kind of what this makes you do.

Comment: @TheMuffinMan: you truly are *the* man! 10 years of working with WPF and just found out about the "Edit Template" option!

Comment: Ho good so I don't have to go fetch those templates myself in C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.18362.0\Generic\generic.xaml
Best tip ever!

Answer (score 121):

This is similar to the solution referred by Mark Heath but with not as much code to just create a very basic button, without the built-in mouse over animation effect. It preserves a simple mouse over effect of showing the button border in black.

The style can be inserted into the Window.Resources or UserControl.Resources section for example (as shown).

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <!-- This style is used for buttons, to remove the WPF default 'animated' mouse over effect -->
    <Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border Name="border" 
                        BorderThickness="1"
                        Padding="4,2" 
                        BorderBrush="DarkGray" 
                        CornerRadius="3" 
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<!-- usage in xaml -->
<Button Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}">Hello!</Button>
```

Comment: I like that solution a lot. However, the mouse over triggers activates only when the mouse is over the text on the button. I added a textblock with a specified width inside the button to fix that problem.

Comment: You sir are a saint.

Answer (score 37):

Just to add a very simple solution, that was good enough for me, and I *think* addresses the OP's issue. I used the solution [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18122450/71833) except with a regular `Background` value instead of an image.

```
<Style x:Key="SomeButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

No re-templating beyond forcing the `Background` to always be the `Transparent` background from the templated button - mouseover no longer affects the background once this is done. Obviously replace `Transparent` with any preferred value.

Answer (score 13):

The Muffin Man had a very simple answer which worked for me.

To add a little more specific direction, at least for VS 2013:

- Right-click the control
- Select Edit Template => Edit a copy...
- I selected 'Application' for where to save the style

  - From here you can directly edit App.xaml and see the intuitively named properties. For my purposes, I just set RenderMouseOver="False"
- Then, in the MainWindow.xaml or wherever your GUI is, you can paste the new style at the end of the Button tag, e.g. `... Style="{DynamicResource MouseOverNonDefault}"/>`

Comment: Who is the Muffin Man?

Comment: LOL. He made the second reply to the question-owner-accepted answer. Wasn't sure if you were asking seriously or joking. Hard to tell with a name like Muffin Man.

Answer (score 11):

This Link helped me alot
http://www.codescratcher.com/wpf/remove-default-mouse-over-effect-on-wpf-buttons/

Define a style in **UserControl.Resources** or **Window.Resources**

```
 <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MyButton" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border Name="border" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Black" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.8" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
```

Then add the style to your button this way **Style="{StaticResource MyButton}"**

```
<Button Name="btnSecond" Width="350" Height="120" Margin="15" Style="{StaticResource MyButton}">
    <Button.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Remove_Default_Button_Effect;component/Images/WithStyle.jpg"></ImageBrush>
    </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 4):

If someone doesn't want to override default Control Template then here is the solution.

You can create DataTemplate for button which can have TextBlock and then you can write Property trigger on IsMouseOver property to disable mouse over effect. Height of TextBlock and Button should be same.

```
<Button Background="Black" Margin="0" Padding="0" BorderThickness="0" Cursor="Hand" Height="20">
    <Button.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="GO" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextDecorations="Underline" Margin="0" Padding="0" Height="20">
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property ="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property= "Background" Value="Black"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Button.ContentTemplate>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

An extension on dodgy_coder's answer which adds support for..

- Maintaining WPF button style
- Adds support for IsSelected and hover, i.e. a toggled button

  ```
      <Style x:Key="Button.Hoverless" TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
          <Setter Property="Template">
              <Setter.Value>
                  <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
                      <Border Name="border"
                              BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                              Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                              BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                              Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                          <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                      </Border>
                      <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                          <MultiTrigger>
                              <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                  <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                                  <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelected" Value="False" />
                              </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                              <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFBEE6FD" />
                          </MultiTrigger>

                          <MultiTrigger>
                              <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                  <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                                  <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelected" Value="True" />
                              </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                              <Setter Property="Background" Value="#BB90EE90" />
                          </MultiTrigger>

                          <MultiTrigger>
                              <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                  <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False" />
                                  <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelected" Value="True" />
                              </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                              <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
                          </MultiTrigger>

                          <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                              <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Opacity" Value="0.95" />
                          </Trigger>
                      </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                  </ControlTemplate>
              </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
      </Style>
  ```

examples..

`<Button Content="Wipe On" Selector.IsSelected="True" />
<Button Content="Wipe Off" Selector.IsSelected="False" />`

Answer (score 1):

Using a template trigger:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"></Setter>
    ...
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```