# What is the property being changed here when hovering?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

What is the property that is causing this blue rectangle to appear on mouse hover for this custom toggle button? I have a feeling this may be a very dumb question but I cannot seem to find the answer by searching. I am somewhat new to XAML but I am learning pretty fast I think. Here are the images of the button on and off mouse hover.

[Button on hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRBa1.png)

[Button off hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mR8Yw.png)

The following is my code for creating this style in a resource dictionary.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}"
           TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}"
           x:Key="ControlButtonToggle">
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                CornerRadius="20">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                              VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style.Setters>

        <Style.Triggers>
            <!-- TRUE TRIGGER -->
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
                     Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                            <Border CornerRadius="10"
                                    Background="LightGreen"
                                    Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                                    Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                                    BorderBrush="Green"
                                    BorderThickness="2">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Rectangle StrokeThickness="1"/>
                                    <Button Margin="1"
                                            Content="Enabled"
                                            BorderThickness="0"
                                            Background="Transparent"
                                            VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                            Padding="5"
                                            Foreground="Black"
                                            BorderBrush="Green"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.8"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>

            <!-- FALSE TRIGGER -->
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
                     Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFF5454"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                            <Border CornerRadius="10"
                                    Background="#FFFF5454"
                                    Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                                    Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                                    BorderBrush="Red"
                                    BorderThickness="2">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Rectangle StrokeThickness="1"/>
                                    <Button Margin="1"
                                            Content="Disabled"
                                            BorderThickness="0"
                                            Background="Transparent"
                                            VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                            Padding="5"
                                            Foreground="Black"
                                            BorderBrush="Red"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.8"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I have tried making the ControlTemplate.Trigger for OnMouseHover change the background and I have made a general trigger outside the ControlTemplate itself but neither has seemed to work. I have searched the properties of the elements of this style but I cannot seem to figure out what is causing this appearance. I would like to either darken the entire rounded field on hover, or just make this property simply transparent as the cursor changes on hover anyways. Any help is greatly appreciated, I apologize if this is a very simple question lol.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove default mouse-over effect on WPF buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854317/how-to-remove-default-mouse-over-effect-on-wpf-buttons)

Comment: @ÉtienneLaneville I'm not sure, would the fact that that solution is a UserControl.Resources make a difference from the fact that mine is a ResourceDictionary?

Comment: You placed a `Button` inside the `ToggleButton` without setting Style to the `Button` and thus the default Style of `Button` which includes MouseOver color is applyed to the `Button`. Nesting `Button` in `ToggleButton` does not make sense in this case.

Comment: @emoacht So would I just be able to change `Button` to `ToggleButton` here then? Or would I need to reproach the style completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now I can't even click on your **ToggleButton** to change its state to: **Enable/Disable**

1. That rectangle is thanks to your **Button** inside **ToggleButton**, why aren't you using **Label** or **TextBlock** instead?
   If you do that, than don't forget to add to your **Grid** `HorizontalAlignment="Center"` to Center your text after that.
2. Or if you don't wanna get rid of your buttons, you can add: `IsHitTestVisible="False"` to those two **Buttons** to disable their styles/click/interaction, but that's not really nice.
3. Or change **Background** of your **Buttons** inside of your **ToggleButton** when **IsMouseOver** is triggered .

Comment: Thank you! #1 worked to fix the rectangle. I have my IsChecked bound to data with INotify so I'm not sure if that is the reason it wouldn't be toggling it's state. Before the change I was manually handling the click event so if that is when you had issues with it then that's why.